# Scala Play List[Any] to JsArray

Tags: scala, play-json

I have a `List[Any]` which I want to convert to a `JsArray`.

List with type works:

```
Json.arr(List("1"))
```

But:

```
Json.arr(List("1").asInstanceOf[List[Any]])
```

throws:

```
diverging implicit expansion for type play.api.libs.json.Reads[T1]
starting with method oFormatFromReadsAndOWrites in object OFormat
```

How can I convert `List[Any]` to `JsArray`?

I tried:

```
implicit val listAnyFormat: OFormat[List[Any]] = Json.format[List[Any]]
```

But I get thrown with:

```
No instance of Reads is available for scala.collection.immutable.Nil in the implicit scope
```

Using Play 2.8.x and Scala 2.11.8

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't.

At least not without defining a `Format[Any]` which can be done technically but will likely not cover all the possible cases.

The question is why do you have a `List[Any]` in the first place? It has not much sense in Scala world.

It would be better if you could have a `List[Something]` where `Something` has a known set of subtypes and each of them has a `Format`.